# Why Lombok's @Builder removes default field value when creating object with default constructor?

Tags: java, lombok

Consider the following code:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void builderTest() throws Exception {
        List<Object> list = new LombokBuilderTest().list;
        assertNotNull(list);
    }
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
class LombokBuilderTest {
    @Builder.Default
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The test fails even though there is default value for `list` property. If you comment `@Builder` annotation it works as expected. Why does Lombok work this way? I expect to have empty `ArrayList` assigned to `list` property when using default constructor.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `LombokBuilderTest.builder().build().list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue ([1](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1347), [2](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/1429)). When you annotate a class with `@Builder` it's "expected" that you'd use the builder to instantiate the class. The problem comes when you use the `@NoArgsConstructor` which bypasses the building process.

The generated code for your example looks something like this:

```
class LombokBuilderTest {

    public static class LombokBuilderTestBuilder {
        private List<Object> list;
        private boolean list$set;

        LombokBuilderTestBuilder() {}

        public LombokBuilderTestBuilder list(final List<Object> list) {
            this.list = list;
            list$set = true;
            return this;
        }

        public LombokBuilderTest build() {
            return new LombokBuilderTest((list$set ? list : LombokBuilderTest.$default$list()));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return (("LombokBuilderTest.LombokBuilderTestBuilder(list=" + this.list) + ")");
        }
    }

    List<Object> list;

    private static List<Object> $default$list() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static LombokBuilderTestBuilder builder() {
        return new LombokBuilderTestBuilder();
    }

    public LombokBuilderTest() {}

    public LombokBuilderTest(final List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new LombokBuilderTest().list;
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

As you can see, your initialized value was *moved* from the field declaration to the `$default$list` method and using the no-agrs constructor is the only way to "corrupt" the instantiation.

As explained in the 2nd link, the reason is that if the assignment expression (`new ArrayList<>()` in your case) is costly, then using the builder would cause the expression to be executed twice which is a performance issue. The workaround would be to write your own no-args constructor and do the field initialization there.